# Django: same method different url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-class-based-views

My url looks like:

```
/api/v1/files/
/api/v1/files/100
```

Is it a good practice to use the same function to match them? just like the following:

```
class FileView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(FileView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, pk = None):
        if pk is not None:
            Do something
        else:
            do something
```

**How to use different functions in Class-based views?**
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think having separate methods is cleaner than a single method that branches based on the `pk`. It's easier to understand which logic goes where by just looking at the view's methods rather than having to follow the (albeit simple) control flow.

My first recommendation would be to check out the [viewsets that Django Rest Framework provides](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) and look at performing your logic within the given methods it provides. This seems like it would best fit your use case.

Another option would be to look DRF's [generic views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#concrete-view-classes) which are based off [these mixins](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#mixins). These allow more control and customization than the viewsets and are sometimes a better option if you don't need all of the functionality provided by the viewsets.

Comment: I already used post/get/delete/. and PUT is not fit in this case. I will read your reference. Thanks

Comment: The viewsets provide methods such as `list`, `retrieve`, and `create`. So, for example, `create` handles a POST to your `/files/` endpoint, `retrieve` handles a GET to your `/files/100` endpoint, and `list` handles a GET to your `/files/` endpoint. Just out of curiosity, what do you want your POST to `/files/100` to do?

Comment: Updating some field of File object

Comment: Then I'd argue that's what PUT and PATCH are for. If you're just updating a single field, then PATCH or the `partial_update` method in the viewset.

Comment: use PUT to create resources, or use POST to update resources? In django rest framework, PUT can be used to create or update?

Comment: Ideally it's POST to create resources, PUT to fully update a resource, and PATCH to update only a few specified fields on a resource.